# How way Revolution slider start (play) again on button click in Version 6.1.8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

I want to replay slider (start again animation)

I have created only 1 slide using Slider Revolution Version 6.1.8
 (https://revolution.themepunch.com/) in WordPress

I have set this slider in popup model.

Actually, I want to replay slider on open popup every time.

I have used **jQuery('#model1').click(function(){ revapi1.revstart();});**

It's working only one time.
Second time it gives

revapi1.revstart();

=> false

=> Slider Is Running Already

So please anyone helps me with replay slider every time when I will open the popup model.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Complete 1st slide.
2. Duplicate 1st slide.  (This for a run (play) on Click event)
   [image]
3. Go to in General setting of the slider.

   - Auto Rotate Slideshow => OFF
   - Wait for API => On
   - Click on Save button
     [image]
4. Go to in CSS/jQuery of General setting of the slider.

   - Click on Custom Js Tab
   - Write below script according to your slider id and Button id.

     ```
     revapi1.revstart();
     var rev_next = 'no';
     jQuery('#ButtonID').click(function(){
       if(rev_next == 'yes'){
         console.log('revstart...');
         revapi1.revstart();
         rev_next = 'yes'
       }else{
         console.log('revnext...');
         revapi1.revnext();
       }
     });
     ```
   - Click on Save button.
     [image]